# parentheses after an alias name

Tags: sql, postgresql

I came across a neat article about using generate_series to create table data. the author does a great job explaining the code, there is however some things I still don't understand. the x after the alias `comp3syl(x)` and `z2(x)` is that assigning the derived table's column name to x? Also what is this syntax called? I'm having trouble googling it's documentation without some keywords

```
SELECT(
SELECT concat_ws(' ',name_first, name_last) as generated
FROM (
    SELECT string_agg(x,'')
    FROM (
        select start_arr[ 1 + ( (random() * 25)::int) % 16 ]
        FROM
        (
            select '{CO,GE,FOR,SO,CO,GIM,SE,CO,GE,CA,FRA,GEC,GE,GA,FRO,GIP}'::text[] as start_arr
        ) syllarr,
        -- need 3 syllabes, and force generator interpretation with the '*0' (else 3 same syllabes)
        generate_series(1, 3 + (generator*0))
    ) AS comp3syl(x)
) AS comp_name_1st(name_first),
(
    SELECT x[ 1 + ( (random() * 25)::int) % 14 ]
    FROM (
        select '{Ltd,& Co,SARL,SA,Gmbh,United,Brothers,& Sons,International,Ext,Worldwide,Global,2000,3000}'::text[]
    ) AS z2(x)
) AS comp_name_last(name_last)
)
FROM generate_series(1,10000) as generator
```

for anyone interested here is the link to the article: https://regilero.github.io/postgresql/english/2017/06/26/postgresql_advanced_generate_series/

Comment: It's a table alias: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLE-ALIASES

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLE-ALIASES):

> Another form of table aliasing gives temporary names to the columns of the table, as well as the table itself:
>
> FROM table_reference [AS] alias ( column1 [, column2 [, ...]] )
>
> If fewer column aliases are specified than the actual table has columns, the remaining columns are not renamed. This syntax is especially useful for self-joins or subqueries.

In the code you gave the `generate_series()` calls aren't aliased in the subqueries themselves so the author names them when he aliases the subquery.

Answer (score 3):

In some databases, but not all, a table alias can take a list of column aliases.  This is how the columns defined by the table alias are referred to.

Consider the following two queries:

```
select *
from (values (1)) x;

select *
from (values (1)) x(a);
```

In the first, the one column returned is unnamed.  In the second, the column is called "a".

The reason for using it with `generate_series()` is that the function returns a column -- a really useful column, in fact.  But how do you refer to it?  I usually use something like `gs(n)` so the column is referred to as `gs.n`.  You can also use just `generate_series() n` and the column can be referred to as either `n` or `n.n`.

For the subquery itself, I always put the column alias inside the subquery.  Not all databases support the naming of columns with table aliases, so it is easier to name the columns in the subquery.